# save re.match in variable to use after elif

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to check a string matching one of various patterns. Is it possible to save the match result while in elif?
To illustrate:

```
if foo = re.match(r'add (.+)', message):
    print(foo.group(1))
elif foo = re.match(r'del (.+)', message):
    print(foo.group(1))
else:
    print("bar")
```

the real use case is a bit more complicated and the use of elif could make it more clearly

Comment: A better way to do it :- http://ideone.com/Jz1Y3v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
add_check = re.match(r'add (.+)', message)
del_check = re.match(r'del (.+)', message)

if add_check:
    print(add_check.group(1))
elif del_check = :
    print(del_check.group(1))
else:
    print("bar")
```

or like this, to only do the second test when the first one doesn't pass:

```
add_check = re.match(r'add (.+)', message)    
if add_check:
    print(add_check.group(1))
else:
    del_check = re.match(r'del (.+)', message)
    if del_check:
        print(del_check.group(1))
    else:
        print("bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

if conditions are for evaluating logical statements and their corresponding truth values to branch logic not for assigning variables. You could set `foo` and `bar` to the respective matches and then test `if foo` / `elif bar` ---> `print(foo/bar.group(1))` like so:

```
foo = re.match(r'add (.+)', message)
bar = re.match(r'del (.+)', message)
if foo:
   print(foo.group(1))
elif bar:
   print(bar.group(1))
else:
   print('fubar')
```